# Type mismatch in CheckSpelling function

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to highlight cells that have grammatical errors in them using

```
Sub ColorMispelledCells()

For Each cl In ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E7199")

**If Not Application.CheckSpelling(Word:=cl.Value) Then _**

cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 28

End If

Next cl

End Sub
```

The line highlighted in asterisks for some reason can't be compiled because of 'Type error'

Comment: I don't get any errors. I did have to declare cl `Dim cl As Variant`  You can also declare it as `Dim cl As Range`

Comment: I am running it on excel 2016, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I installed Excel 2016 and it works fine for me there too.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
Sub ColorMispelledCells()
    Dim Ap As Object, c As String
    Set Ap = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim cl As Range, boo As Boolean

    For Each cl In ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E7199")
        c = cl.Text
        If Not Ap.CheckSpelling(c) Then
            cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 28
        End If
    Next cl
    Set Ap = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: If Not Ap.CheckSpelling(c) Then - seems to trigger the same error